# Automating Javascript and CSS minification in Symfony 1.4

Tags: javascript, php, css, symfony-1.4, minify

I have several websites running on Symfony 1.4 on a SVN repositiory, that uses a lot of javascript and css files. My current process is to manually minify the files before putting them live on production. I have tried to use a few plugins that i found online but they don't work with my websites, I have worked with the developers of the plugins and still couldn't resolve the issues.

I was wondering if anyone had any other solutions.

I am using PHP5, SVN and Symfony 1.4, no databases.

Comment: Did you simply tried this ? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/uglifyjs.html

Comment: @Akaryatrh that's for Symfony 2 ^^

Comment: Awww, sorry i didn't noticed Sf version :/ You still can use a side tool that live process your files, like Brunch (http://brunch.io/) It probably requires a bit of configuration to match your Sf architecture, but it worths a try :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for Symfony 1.4 that both minifies and combines JavaScript and CSS files called sfCombinePlugin [git repo](https://github.com/heristop/sfCombinePlugin) and the [plugin page](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfCombinePlugin)

I'm currently using it in production and it works well.